# Plugin action is not enabled

Tags: intellij-plugin

Created a basic plugin with the action .
But the action is not enabled until the indexing of the project is done . Could anyone help to remove that behaviour.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Code related actions are unavailable during indexing because they **need** the index in order to function. From the [IntelliJ Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/indexing.html):

> While indexing is in progress, the above-mentioned coding assistance features are unavailable or partially available. Nevertheless, you can still work with the IDE: you can type code, work with VCS features, configure settings, and perform other code unrelated actions.

For example, IntelliJ indexes all methods used in each file, so that when you use the find usages action on a method it can query the index instead of having to look through all the files to find the usages.

There is no way to disable this behaviour, however, you might be able to speed up indexing so it is less of a problem. The tips given in this [JetBrains blog about improving performance](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/06/simple-steps-for-improving-your-ide-performance/#tips) might be helpful.

Comment: The action is just taking some input from the user and triggering a command line command . So I guess it would not be depending on the code.

Comment: @Override
    public void actionPerformed(@NotNull AnActionEvent anActionEvent) {
        Messages.showMessageDialog("hi","Hello mEssage",Messages.getInformationIcon());
    } This is also waiting for indexing

Comment: @AbhiramReddy Could you update your question so it contains your action and how you've registered it in the plugin? (So a minimal class with your action, and the relevant lines in `plugin.xml`.) Then I can reproduce it and see what's going on, so I can provide some more targeted help.